# React-leaflet custom component for mapquest routing

Tags: reactjs, leaflet, react-leaflet, mapquest

I am trying to create a custom react-leaflet component for the mapquest routing api ([Documentation](https://developer.mapquest.com/documentation/leaflet-plugins/routing/)). 
But I am getting error when I am adding the leaflet element to the map as '*The provided object is not a Layer.'* But the `MQ.Routing.routeLayer` is being accepted as a layer in the mapquest documentation leaflet sample
This is the [codesandbox link](https://codesandbox.io/s/react-leaflet-mapquest-routing-krg7q) (can see actual error message in browser console)

Comment: The codesandbox does not work.

Comment: yes, it is throwing error because of 'this.leafletElement.addTo(this.props.leaflet.map);'
 with the given message in console. Getting same in application too

Comment: No, i get `A cross-origin error was thrown. React doesn't have access to the actual error object in development.`

Comment: yes. codesandbox won't show most of the real errors when the error object is big enough. Shall open browser console to find that. Let me know if it would be easy for you to try if I host the same in jsfiddle/stackblitz.

Answer (score 0):

MapQuest Routing Plugin is not compatible with Leaflet `v1` or above (the latest version of `react-leaflet` utilizes leaflet `1.5.1`) That's the reason why the error occurs in the first place.

[The official documentation also recommends](https://developer.mapquest.com/forum/mapquest-routing-plugin-leaflet-compatibility-leaflet-v10) to to switch from MapQuest Routing Plugin to `MapQuest.js` library (which is compatible with `leaflet v1`).

And finally [this is the answer](https://developer.mapquest.com/forum/mq-react-leaflet) from the support team regarding integrating `react leaflet` with MapQuest:

> MapQuest.js is not compatible with React Leaflet. It was never
>   intended to be. There is no plan to support it at this time.